# Android GridLayout - Half of the screen

Tags: java, android

I have a GridLayout with 2 columns. I want the ImageButtons to have half of the width of the screen for the width and as for the height it should be the same as the width, since the image is a square.

This is what I have and I've played with these configurations but I can't make it. New to Android development.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/food0t"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/food0t"/>


    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the expected result:
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout for this design

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.SplashActivity">




        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/img4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img2" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```